# What is explicit isomorphism between $H^2(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then its Schur multiplier is the second cohomology group $H^2(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, which is isomorphic to the second homology group $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ (Proof can be seen in An Introduction to Homological Algebra by J J Rotman). I am unable to figure out an explicit isomorphism between them. Can someone help me to get an isomorphism?

Comment: There's no natural isomorphism. $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is naturally isomorphic to the *dual* $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(H^2(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ of $H^2(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, and the isomorphism you quote follows because every finite abelian group is isomorphic (non-naturally) to its dual.